What was the impact of international sanctions on the fall of Assad's regime?
Bashar Al-Assad's regime in Syria was placed under international sanctions in 2011 due to the violent response to peaceful protests in the country and the evolving civil war. 13 years later, the oppositional forces steamrolled the regime after support from Iran and Hezbollah subsided due to their intense conflict with Israel.
I wonder, is there a way to determine if and how the sanctions have facilitated that regime change in the long run by denying Assad's regime certain resources etc.? And how can this be placed into context with other sanctions currently in place, e.g. for Iran, North Korea, and Russia?
Were sanctions effective in Syria (even if it took 13 years...) ?

About the general efficacy of sanctions see https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/75045/21531

A clear answer will only be possible in a few years from now once researchers have worked through various documents, if ever. However, we can assess whether it is plausible that the sanctions had a meaningful impact.
I have read reports that many soldiers in the Syrian army had not been paid for several months right before the Assad's regime collapsed. Since the main problem for Assad was that his soldiers didn't put up much of a fight, it seems very plausible that:
a) The sanction led to Assad having less money to pay troops with.
b) The soldiers would have been more willing to fight if they got paid.
I also read a interview with some Syrians who had fled from Aleppo to Idlib a few years ago, and now returned. They remarked that the salvation government in Idlib had done a much better job at the basics of local government compared to the Assad government in Aleppo (policing, collecting rubbish, stuff like that). (They said they weren't fond of HTS' religious policies, so probably not paid actors.) This, too, shows that a lack of resources for the Assad government led to a reduced support by the general population.
Of course there are also very important factors completely unrelated to the sanctions, eg the losses Hezbollah took against Israel, rendering them unable to provide meaningful support to Assad.

This is not strictly answerable.
Before December 2024, many experts would have cited Syria as an example of sanctions not working to remove a regime.
Now some of those will talk it up as an example of sanctions working, while others will use the fact military action threw out Assad as "proof" that sanctions would have never worked.
But then you can argue that sanctions a) weakened supplies and arms to Syria's army (not all that much, since they were armed by Russia) and b) demotivated the soldiers as they were poor and fed up with the general economy.  Still, at the end of the day, Syrian troops in Idlib and Hama collapsed for their own immediate morale and military reasons and sanctions were most likely not their uppermost preoccupation when they decided to desert and rout.
So both sides can probably make a valid case.  If you look at South Africa, easily the gold standard when it comes to these things plenty of experts argue either side - that the sanctions worked or that they did not work and here.
Sanctions were a factor in weakening Syria's economy, army and Assad's appeal.  Whether he would have been overthrown without them is unknowable, but they certainly did not help him.
A number of countries under sanction have "come to see the light", one way or another,

Lybia re. its nuclear programs
South Africa
Syria
...

A number have not:

Cuba
Russia wrt Ukraine
North Korea
Iran
Venezuela
Iraq under Saddam
USSR's Afghanistan invasion.

Basically, sanctions work very slowly, if at all.  Given the time gap between their start and the removal/"repentance" of a regime, it is easy to argue the case that something else fixed the problem.  But how do you prove that?  And, conversely how to you prove that the problem would have taken just as long to fix, absent the sanctions?
Unless of course the government comes right out and states "we changed because of sanctions".  But that's a loss of face that should not be expected to take place in most cases.
To take another example, Cuba is facing some major, obviously sanctioned-related problems, such as fuel and electricity shortages and occasional mass unrest.  But as the government is still in power, for now it counts in the "don't work" camp.  But what if the government collapses in the next 5-10 years?  The sanctions themselves will not have changed, but the discourse around their efficacy most certainly will.
Last, sanctions are not necessarily an all or nothing item.  Yes, Russia can still import microchips to put into their missiles.  But if they have to pay 3x as much to source them and it takes twice as long, surely that is not negligible either for those on the receiving end of Russian aggression.  In that case, they increase friction and make weapon manufacture harder.
Ditto Iran.  Their theocracy is still around after 40 years, but they would have a lot better air force if they had kept access to the international arms market, instead of flying museum displays.

How do sanctions work? A government puts another government's people into trouble, the people object to their own government for their new difficulties, the sanctioned government invites its people to bear the difficulties and resist against those who want to dictate their will to them. There comes a time when individuals among the people start to rebel. The sanctioned government explains to its people that the problem is not intrinsic to itself but is due to the sanctions another government applies against them, but some individuals fight against this story and instead tell their own story that the foreigners are so kind and whatever they do is for the sake of our own benefit. Then a rebellion is formed. In such a game, both sides may make several mistakes, and the foreigners may misuse the mistakes and make the troubles even more profound in the eyes of both sides, with lies and directed news spread among the true news. ... So sanctions can have their role in making people dissatisfied with their own government, and thus rebel, and in making a government fall. Sanctions put pressure against people, for the people to press against their government, for the government to either submit to the sanctioner, or to remain in troubles and even perhaps tear apart. Syria was not an exception in how to react against sanctions. But why is this not working so easily in Iran? Or why did it work in Syria even after so many years? Maybe I can refer you to what Sayyed Hashim Al-Heidari, an Iraqi leader in the axis of resistance, said in a speech he had at the beginning of the rebels in Syria some weeks ago (ref):

One feels saddened by the events in Syria, but this is where the difference between an Islamic government and other governments becomes clear. Here (in Iran), there is faith, there is leadership, there is the representative of the Imam of the Time PBUH, not just a government with some weapons, an army, and intelligence... An Islamic government cannot be established merely with resistance, a military, weapons, and a few missiles; governance means the Imam and the community.

People who defend such a system as Iran understand their defense as sacred, and will not be scared of being martyred for their beliefs, and rather prefer to be killed in this way than to die of illness or accident. I guess this is why sanctions are not working in Iran. In Iran, for those who believe in Islam, the leader is a man of God, the representative of Imam of the present era, Imam Mahdi PBUH. Listening to such a man is like listening to the Imam and that is like listening to God. Compare it to a government which is only a government. That Assad could withstand the sanctions for many years might have been due to help he received from other foreigners, like Iran. And now countries like Russia learn the ways a country like Iran uses to stand up against sanctions and even improve in several aspects, while being anyway in troubles dictated to it due to sanctions by dictator countries like the Westerners, the US and its allies. Sanctioning is anyway a manner of dictatorship in modern politics, and it was even in ancient times.
All that being said, it is not the case that the Syrian people really conducted the rebellion and caused Assad to fall, as the rebels came from many different nations, even including Chinese jihadists. It may be more accurate to conclude that the dissatisfaction stemming from the troubles caused by these sanctions and the mistakes made by Assad, rendered people inactive against the rebels. This situation is quite similar to how the Taliban took over Afghanistan in a very short period of time a few years ago. Even Afghan Shia soldiers who had already fought against ISIS (in Syria and Iraq) remained inactive during that time. Not resisting is somewhat different from rebelling on their own.
PS, the statement that 'after support from Iran and Hezbollah subsided due to their intense conflict with Israel' is not entirely accurate. Assad received Iran's assistance but preferred to refuse the help, although the news on this matter is somewhat unclear. Some reports suggest that Assad was afraid to accept help from Iran, as this could provoke Israel to open a war on Syria, so he preferred to keep Syria safe in this regard. However, he later realized that his army would not defend him either. According to these reports, Assad was inactive for almost a year in the axis of resistance, only allowing the axis of resistance to use its territory, but for example, he did not permit resistance groups like the Houthis to take the Golan Heights. Other reports indicate that Assad relied on promises made to him by Saudi Arabia, Turkey, and Western powers, distancing himself to some extent from the axis of resistance. Additionally, the Syrian army was reportedly influenced by Western powers, leaving the country defenseless, and Iran and Hezbollah had no opportunity to become his entire army, which is why they stayed away from the conflict on this basis.

This answer requires the underlying assumption that all sanctions are for the purpose of a regime change in the sanctioned country. This is not true though. Sanctions in Iran have been highly effective.

@DavidS, no I didn't mean to conclude such, but to make them submit, otherwise to change them. Sanctions are to dictate the mind change, either only the minds or the bodies which have those minds. Sanctions are always effective, but the effect might be mere troubles and no mind-change, or body-change, this is the problem. If in Iran you hear many have experienced mind-change that is true by the way, but they are not the majority.
